# React FirebaseError DocumentReference.set()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Please can someone help me. I think the way I am handling the promise is wrong and really need someone to help me.

I am letting the user upload a picture . When the user presses submit the image is uploaded to firebase-storage. However I don't think I am handling the wait period to upload the image and setting the data to firebase-database. What I mean is when I press submit I get the error `FireBase Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data` Because it is setting the image to `undefined`

However if I wait a couple of seconds I get the `console.log("File available at" + downloadUrl)` which means the image was uploaded.

Basically I just need to add a waiting period to my code between when the image is uploaded and when to send the data to the `firebase-database`

This is my code any help will be much appreciated !!!!!

```
const uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await response.blob()
    var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`images/${imageName}`)
    ref.put(blob)

    .then(()=>{
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + imageName)
        storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl)=>{
        console.log(`File available at ${downloadUrl}`)
        setDownload(JSON.stringify(downloadUrl))
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setRefreshing(false) // false isRefreshing flag for disable pull to refresh
        Alert.alert("An error occured", "Please try again later")
      });
}

const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    if (postImage !== undefined) {
        const fileExtention = postImage[0].split('.').pop()
        const fileName = `${uniqid}.${fileExtention}`
        uploadImage(postImage, fileName)
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Posts')
        .doc(uniqid)
        .set({
            id: currentUser,
            name: postName[0],
            image: downloadImage,
        })
    }         
})
```

Thank you in advance for all your help!!!!!

Comment: adding `await` to `firebase.firestore()` bloc in `handleSubmit` solves the issue?

Comment: Yeah but I can’t use `await` with `useCallback` in the `handleSubmit` right? If I can please show me how

Comment: Also I added await and made `handleSubmit` async and now the handleSubmit doesn't even work or get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use await inside `useCallback` you can try to wrap the code inside it in a self invoking function like this:

```js
 
const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
   (async () =>{ if (postImage !== undefined) {
        const fileExtention = postImage[0].split('.').pop()
        const fileName = `${uniqid}.${fileExtention}`
        uploadImage(postImage, fileName)
        await firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Posts')
        .doc(uniqid)
        .set({
            id: currentUser,
            name: postName[0],
            image: downloadImage,
        })
    } 
  })()        
})
```